# Reactjs Cant declare and export a constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to export this keys to app.js but cant do it  showing this error :-

'const' can only be used in a .ts file.

ApiKey.js

```
import React from 'react';

const firebaseConfig;
export default class firekeys extends React.Component {
     const firebaseConfig ={
        apiKey: "key",
          authDomain: "auth",
          databaseURL: "url",
          projectId: "Id",
          storageBucket: "",
          messagingSenderId: "SID"
    }
};
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import firekeys from "./constants/ApiKeys"
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.initializeApp(firekeys.firebaseConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite ApiKeys.js as follows, unless you have some specific reason for needing them in a component:

```
export default firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "key",
  authDomain: "auth",
  databaseURL: "url",
  projectId: "Id",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "SID"
}
```

`import firekeys from "./constants/ApiKeys"` (to be fair the variable you name them isn't important)

Then you should be able to access the keys as follows

`firekeys.apiKey`

You should probably take a look at the different ways to use let, var and const https://medium.com/podiihq/javascript-variables-should-you-use-let-var-or-const-394f7645c88f

Answer (score 2):

Two issues I see here:
1. You can't redeclare a `const`.
2. Your are exporting your class, not the `const`.  Furthermore, you should be assigning class properties to your React class, not variables.  Below should work but you'll need to import `firebaseConfig` as a named export.

```
export const firebaseConfig ={
    apiKey: "key",
      authDomain: "auth",
      databaseURL: "url",
      projectId: "Id",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "SID"
}

export default class firekeys extends React.Component {

};
```